# Getting real time data for a set of symbols from BINANCE API

Tags: python, binance, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to retrieve the latest information about a set of Binance symbols every, say, 15 seconds, using the `binance-connector-python` library.

For example: `pairs=['BTCUSDT','ETHUSDT',...]`

I can do it by using:

```
info=[spot_client.klines(pair, "1s", limit=1)['data'] for pair in pairs]
```

but this will make multiple calls, which takes a fair amount of time and therefore fails to get me real time data. This method, as far as I could check, doesn't let me ask for information about more than one symbol at a time.

I also tried with:

```
spot_client.ticker_price(symbols=pairs)
```

but the information retrieved by this method is updated every minute, which, again, fails to  get real time data.

Is there a method in the `binance-connector-python` library that I can use to get real time information about a set of symbols?

Comment: You want to create a websocket connection and subscribe for the Symbol Price Ticker.

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#symbol-price-ticker

Comment: @DonCoder could you elaborate on your answer? I'm not an engineer and I wasn't able to understand the purpose of the refered documentation